# How To Get All Element of Array before last one in Java

Tags: java, string

I am able to get last element of array but unable to get all element except last one. 
Here is my code by which I get last element of array after split:

```
class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s ="23+43*435/675-90";
      String[] ss = s.split("[-+*/]");
      String last=ss[ss.length-1];
      System.out.println(last);     
   }
}
```

This code return me 90 but now I also want it to return result like `23+43*435/675-` the given string can be smaller or larger.

Comment: Please elaborate that do you want to skip the last value form String?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
    String s ="23+43*435/675-90";
    s = s.replaceAll("(.*[-+*/]).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
23+43*435/675-
```

Comment: it says take all chars till the last separator (inclusive as you wanted) and remember them as group 1. Then replace the whole string with group 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
String whatYouWant = s.substring(0, s.length() - last.length());
```

Comment: Add more detail to your answer.

Comment: There is a better answer by @Evgeniy Dorofeev, so people should use it. Thus there is no need for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s ="23+43*435/675-90";
    String[] ss = s.split("[-+*/]");
    String last=ss[ss.length-1];
    System.out.println(last);
    String except_last = s.substring(0, s.length() - last.length());
    System.out.println(except_last);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as identical elements in the middle with identical content compared with the last element will also be removed.

Answer (score -3):

Your best bet is:

```
String[] s3 = new String[ss.length-1];
System.arraycopy(ss, 0, s3, 0, ss.length-1);
```

Or do it in Python.

Unfortunately there's no convenient way to join your subarray back into a string, but if a subarray is what you want, then you're good to go.

Comment: 'Or do it in Python'? Really?

Comment: Sure, why not?  Depending on the problem OP is trying to solve, there are other languages more suitable to the task.

Comment: so to solve just one problem, you wont mind rewriting the whole code?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the problem OP is trying to solve.  I've often rewritten an entire program once I realized I was using the wrong language.

Comment: Speaking of which, what *is* OP trying to solve?  Did he want to return the sub-array excluding the last element?  If so, I believe my answer is the correct one.  Is he looking for a substring?  Then one of the other answers is probably correct.

Comment: That's unfortunate: this is the only answer that actually answers the title question, yet it's downvoted due to that (a bit unfortunate) remark about python. Otherwise, +1